# how to Get All tokens against a specific Walllet Addresse?

Tags: blockchain, tokens, wallets, chaindata, code

Is It Possible to get All tokens against a specific wallet Address , whether it is deployed on a ethereum blockchain , solna , polygone or whatever ?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an article that explains [how to retrieve the balance of all ERC20 tokens from a wallet](https://chainstack.com/ultimate-guide-erc20-token-balance/). It works with multiple blockchains (Ethereum, BNB, Polygon, Avalanche) and you can even check in a specific date.

Answer (score 0):

There is no answer to how, but yes it is possible because all the data on a those blockchains are public

Check this article (written yesterday):
https://medium.com/coinmonks/how-do-i-get-all-the-tokens-21ff1607d189